# MySQL command not found in Docker container

Tags: mysql, alpine-linux

After getting a terminal into a Docker container (postgres:11.1-alpine) and installing MySQL using apk (apk add mysql) I still receive `sh: mysql: not found` and `bash: mysql: command not found` when trying to run mysql. What am I misunderstanding about apk that is preventing the mysql command from being found?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem today. I found out that the default version of MySQL that Alpine installs when running `apk add mysql` is only the server, not the client which includes binaries. See https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Mysql

The way to get them is to install mysql-client as well:
`apk add mysql-client`

For more options run `apk search mysql`